# Single call-by-name constructor arg not required?

Tags: scala

Why does line #2 below compile? It's (seemingly) not giving the required constructor arg.

```
class F(x: => Unit) {}
new F                     // Compiles (strange)
def f(x: =>Unit) = ()
f                         // Does not compile (good)
```

Is it permitted sugar just for this special case? Can you point to docs on the subject? I'm using Scala 2.9.0.

Comment: An anecdote, I found this because the following printed "KO" instead of "OK".

`class F(x: => Unit) {x; print("K")}`
`new F{print("O")}`

I wrongly assumed I could use braces instead of parens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Scala Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> **5.1.1 Constructor Invocations**
>
> If no explicit arguments are given, an
>   empty list **() is implicitly supplied**.

,where `()` stands for `Unit`

Comment: Does that make it obvious how it differs from functions?  That class didn't allow for an empty list of parameters, and methods also use a single empty parameter list in place of no parameter list.

Comment: As I understand it, if no parameters are specified for constructor, `()`(~> `Unit`) is passed as an argument, which is not the case for functions that can be partially applied.

Comment: E.g., the following will compile too: `class F(a: Any)`; `new F`

Comment: That isn't obvious to me from what you quoted.  `()` can be `Unit`, but it is also an empty parameter list.  Given the phrasing `empty list ()`, I would have assumed that it is _not_ passing the unique instantiation of type `Unit`, `()`, but is rather passing an empty parameter list.

Comment: I agree, it's a confusing definition (in the spec), but I still think that `()` in this context is `Unit`. At least, it behaves so. Here's how the decompiled bytecode looks like: https://gist.github.com/987007

Comment: If `()` is actually the instance of `Unit` but is called `empty list ()` in the spec, then I'd say it is either a bug in the code or a bug in the spec.

Comment: Also from the spec (p. 181): "Scala version 2.0 now automatically applies methods with empty parameter lists to () argument lists when necessary." This seems pretty similar to the definition in this answer.